# Why did the results still returned latest data values when already set `execution_boundary_time` to historical date in Apache IoTDB?

Tags: apache-iotdb, iotdb

I have a problem of continuous query when using Version 1.2.2 of Apache IoTDB. I set `execution_boundary_time` configuration to yesterday’s date, but when I try to query data results, the timestamp returned is still today’s latest data. I want to know what other configuration should I set or changed to fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

`execution_boundary_time` in Apache IoTDB indicates the execution time of the first periodic task of the continuous query expected by the user. Only the current real-time stream will be calculated, and past timestamps will not be calculated. Since continuous query will only calculate the current real-time data flow, the actual execution time of the first periodic task of the continuous query is not necessarily equal to the time specified by the user.